# Why doesn't FactoryBot save passwords in the test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have just run into a situation where I had to tack down why my test user could not login in a system test.

It turns out that the password word for the user was nil.

I ran binding.pry after a user is created:

```
it 'some tests do
  user = create(:user)
  binding.pry
end

   user.password = '12345' # correct
   User.last.password = nil # wtf

   user.email = 'joe@example.com' #correct
   User.last.email = 'joe@example.com' #correct
```

Does anyone know why passwords are not persisted into the database with FactoryBot?

Comment: I Never came across this issue... normally I have no problems saving passwords. Are you sure the user is being persisted? Could it be that the password is giving validation issues, due to pattern or size? Normally devise hides the password attribute for security reasons, could this be causing it?

Comment: The user is persisted as I get all of the data back about the user. It's just the password and it's not a validation issue.  As I'm looking at the user from doing User.first I don't think Devise comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `User.last.password` is nil is because the plain text password is encrypted and not accessible. Check your `schema.rb` file...you should only see an encrypted_password column (I'm assuming you are using Devise).

To check if the User is persisted just check `user.persisted?`, `user.errors`, or something of the sort to figure out whats going on.

Comment: That was exactly it. Cudoz to @bo-oz for actually indicating something along those lines but I was too noob to realize how devise stores the password in an encrypted_password column. Thanks for your help.